# What is the best way to add a back button to custom toolbars?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar

So i know how to add a backwards navigation button to my custom toolbar, however there must be a more efficient way to add the functionality to multiple activities than copying and pasting this code in each one...

```
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tlbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

I've tried making a common class were i create a function that could be called in each activity however you need to `findViewById` which can only be done in the activity. Any suggestions around this?

Comment: Make a BaseActivity which is extended by all activity and put your toolbar code in BaseActivity by this way you have to only write code once.

Comment: How exactly would i create one that extends all activities? i tried this earlier but as i mentioned functions like `findViewById` had errors because it could not find the widgets

Comment: Here take look at this demo. I have created `BaseActivity` here.
https://github.com/pt147/MVVM-Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create a base class like this

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    public  void setToolbar(@IdRes int toolbarID){
        try {
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(toolbarID);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

After extends all Activity class with BaseActivity class

```
public class LoginNewActivity extends BaseActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setToolbar(R.id.toolbar); //You can call your method like this
    }
}
```

If you want to know more about this do search for **Inheritance and polymorphism in JAVA**

Answer (score 0):

in your activity tag on manifest add parentactivityname and add value as an activity which you want to go when back pressed.this is the best solution for you.